# Prestashop 1.6.1.11 (500) Internal server error (Associations) bytes exhausted

Tags: php, caching, prestashop

I've had a question posted on the Prestashop forums for some time regarding an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. I'll post the link below to the original question, any assistance I can get regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[Initial Prestashop Forum Question.](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/601133-16111-500-internal-server-error-associations/)

---

Prestashop 1.6.1.11: Everytime I access certain products and try to edit thier associations I receive an error notice;

> **(500 Internal Server Error)**
>
> *A server error occurred while loading the tabs: some tabs could not be
>   loaded. Please try again by refreshing the page. If you are still
>   encountering this problem, please check your server logs or contact
>   your hosting provider for assistance.*

I completed a few steps to try to identify the error as shown below in my code snippet, a result of which I was able to return a few details regarding the error.

```
<php

// I enabled dev mode via config/defines.inc.php
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
}

?>
```

> **Re-tracing the steps I tried to reccur the error.**
>
> This was my result...
>
> *Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /classes/cache/CacheFs.php on line 69*

I took a few steps forward in hopes of correcting this issue but all to no avail. I'll list the steps I've attempted below;

- Adjusted my php.ini to allow the full memory limit, I'll post a full copy of which below. `(memory_limit = 128M)`
- Contacted my hosting provider to have the 'xCache' caching module installed on my sever in hopes of worming my around the default caching solution and finding a possible fix. However this is not possible at this time.
- Checked for recently installed module issues. (None found)

---

I have done some further digging on the web but most solutions seem exstensive, such as rebuilding the code to be less memory intensive. Sadly, I'm not confident enough in my ability to reliably resolve this issue with my current knowledge and I'm seeking some advice on how to go about resolving this error.

Regards,
-B

**EDIT**

After further digging and after disabling caching, my error location has changedto; `Adapter/Adapter_EntityMapper.php on line 98`.

Comment: The error seems to indicate you have a `memory_limit` of `128M`, as you pointed out in your first bullet point. Have you tried increasing it ?

Comment: @roberto06 yes, I have tried increasing it to (256M), all to no avail. :(

Comment: Did it show in your phpinfo when you increased it ? And did the error change ?

Comment: Yes it showed in the info file, the error was persistant.

Comment: If the error is still the same (i.e. with the same number), it means your php.ini directive has not been taken into account.

Comment: You can see all php info, here. (https://mymgi.co.uk/phpinfo.php)

Comment: Your `memory_limit` is still `128M`

Comment: I reverted the changes after testing. I have amended it back now for proofing.

Comment: OK so now that the `memoty_limit`is set to `256M`, your error message should be different (i.e. the number should not be `134217728` anymore). Is that the case ?

Comment: You're right the integer increased. `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8724 bytes) in /classes/cache/CacheFs.php on line 69`

Comment: Ok, now you have two ways to make this error disappear, either increase it again *(dirty way)*, or find out which tab(s) is(are) causing this error. I remember having a similar problem on PS 1.5 (or was it 1.4 ?), I went with the dirty way after a couple of days of self-hair-pulling.

Comment: From prior experience I'm confident in saying that the tabs in question throwing this error is the associations tab.

Comment: Try to disable non-prestashop modules and overrides in backoffice `Advanced parameters -> Performance` and check if the problem still persists. If the problem goes away then you have a faulty module or override. If not then I think it's gonna be next to impossible to find the problem without someone digging and debugging through the actual code.

Comment: @TheDrot This is one of the first things I did, sadly the issue persists. It's come to the point where I think we may have to pay for some support to get this issue resolved...

Comment: Based on the latest edit, try to dump the $object_datas and $cache_id where that error occurs. Also, you mention it only happens with certain products. Is there a pattern with the ones that work than the ones that don't? Maybe some integrity issues with the data in database (could cause an infinite loop, for example).

Comment: can you create a `testfile.php` to show this function what returns `phpinfo()` and then look for `memory_limit` if is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have exhausted 128M and also exhausted 1024M, which is ludicrous (actually, 128M is pretty ludicrous in its own right).

This isn't likely to be a standard leak; looks more like a looped allocation. It's almost as if the entity mapper found a link to *another* entity that, by a commodius vicus of recirculation, brought back to the first entity. When trying to resolve the Entity-Relationship-Attribute graph, each loops allocates more memory in a nested structure, until all available memory is exhausted.

Just as an example, and not even in PHP:

```
ProductA: {
    Name: "Phone charger",
    Details: {
         Accessories: {
             ProductB: {
                 Name: "Phone charger cable",
                 Details: {
                     Accessories: {
                         ProductA: {
                             Name: "Phone charger",
                             Details: {
                                 ...
```

Can you verify whether your product attribute structure is identical between one of the products that work, and one that does not?

Comment: You have no idea how much pain I've been in looking for this damned loop. +1. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable all the overrides to see if the problem is there:

1. Enable debug mode/error reporting, setting the config value _PS_MODE_DEV_ to true in config/defines.inc.php

`define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`

2. Log into your PrestaShop 1.6 administration dashboard.
3. Click on the Advanced Parameters menu option located on the left sidebar and after that on Performance.
4. Toggle the Disable All Overrides button in the debug mode section